# Changing shape of some sections-paragraph

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I am working on my dissertation in Overleaf (documentclass book).

I would like to change the shape of the section-paragraphs' title from bold to small caps italics.
However, this change should not be set as a default for every section-paragraph title, but just for some examples.
So far, I have tried `\paragraph{\itshape \textsc{mind is a container}} \upshape`
This usually works in the text, but not for the section-paragraph title.

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it your habit to post code with these properties: a) starts with \documentclass, ends with \end{document}, b) shows all relevant (only those) packages you use, c) provides your relevant code, d) drops all code not needed. This way we can copy, compile and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never want to put font commands in a heading, the same text appears in the section heading, the table of contents, pdf bookmarks, possibly the page head; different fonts are needed in each case.

In `book`, `\paragraph` is defined by

```
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

so in your preamble define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xparagraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\itshape\scshape}}
\makeatother
```

Computer modern doesn't have italic small caps so I use tx fonts here

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xparagraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\itshape\scshape}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Aaaa Xyz} bbb

\xparagraph{Aaaa xyz} bbb
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But this means that all my section-paragraphs' titles will appear in italic small caps, right? 
I only want some of them in italic small caps, whenever the title of a section-paragraph is the same as a conceptual metaphor (therefore needs to be in italic small caps).

Comment: No, only when you use `\xparagraph` instead of `\paragraph`.

Comment: @Sarah No. As Igmar says, and also as shown in the example I posted which has one bold and one  italic small caps heading.

Comment: Thank you so much!